# Where should I ask a question about theatre?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question I'd like to ask about live stage performances (distinct from filmed adaptations) and what I think would be a principle of theatre. It's not about a script, so it doesn't fit in the Literature beta, and it's not genre-specific to go on something like the Sci-fi & Fantasy SE.

Should I go ahead and post it on Movies & TV since that's the closest SE?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I go ahead and post it on Movies & TV since that's the closest SE?

I'm afraid the answer is...

## NO

We don't cover theatre productions unless they are **specifically** related to Movie/TV productions.

Questions about *filmed* theatrical productions *could* be on topic, as could questions about Movie or TV *adaptations* of the stage plays etc but otherwise I'm afraid not.

However, a quick glance at Literature.SE does show there are *some* questions involving staged productions so perhaps this question should be cross-posted in their Meta.

I suspect that the answer will be "it depends on the question".

Comment: What about DTH services showing theater play?

Comment: I have no idea what DTH means

Comment: Direct-to-home television  service/dish tv.

Comment: Ah....which is the same as *filmed* theatrical productions which I mentioned.

Comment: I've just asked [Could this question about stage aspects of this TV personality's career be on-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4605/45856)